# ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined

Tags: bloodhound

I am trying to use Twitter's Typehead with Bloodhound, via NPM, and am getting the above error.  I have seen other questions (and fixes) which are similar, but don't involve NPM.

I am using Laravel 5.5 and Webpack.  First, I installed typeahead.js and bloodhound.js using NPM.  I required both packages in my `bootstrap.js` and ran `npm run dev`.  Typeahead worked fine, but I got the error when I tried to issued `new Bloodhound()`.

I then uninstalled these packages and installed https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js.  Again, I ran `npm run dev`, but still got the error above.

UPDATE: I just installed typeahead.js using bower, then included it directly in to my files.  That worked fine.